# can't open file django-admin.py, no such file error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to start a django project in Cygwin with: `django-admin.py startproject mysite` However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Python34/Scripts/django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My PATH in Windows include paths to "django-admin.py":

```
...;C:\cygwin64;C:\cygwin64\usr\sbin;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;...
```

Comment: Why would django-admin.py be in the Python distribution script directory?

Comment: It's in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\bin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
django-admin runserver
```

try this

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\github\django\Scripts\django-admin.py runserver
```

here the django stands for virtual environment